# Should the primary key of my MySQL database change when I update my row?

Tags: java, mysql, reactjs, spring-boot, rest

I have a spring boot website project I am working on and I've created a react.js app for the front end. When I submit a PUT command from the app and change the column "position", my primary key updates along with the row to a new unique value. Is this the way PUT operations should work or did I build my backend API incorrectly? Here is the code for the Restful API:

```java
// Update @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000") @RequestMapping(value = "/images/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT) public ResponseEntity
<Object> updateImage(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody ImageModel image) {
        imageRepository.deleteById(id);
        image.setId(id);
        imageRepository.save(image);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Image is updated successsfully", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Just want to make sure I didn't make anything that would break my database later on.

Comment: Implemented in the wrong way. In @RequestBody are you binding id field inside image object ?

Comment: why delete and insert on update ? A fetch on id and update is the right way .

Comment: Here's a full list of circumstances under which your PRIMARY KEY should change:

Comment: This is my first time building a RESTful API and the tutorial I used built the function in that way. @Strawberry, I don't see the list you mentioned.

Comment: That's my point!

Comment: HAHAHAHA!! Ok, I gotcha!